# iterate v-for depending on selected input number

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, rendering

i want to achieve the following: if user selects input X (which is a number, lets say 1, 2, 3 ... 10) i want to render a specific other vue component also x times. it works if i go about it with saying v-for n in 10 but not if i use variables.

```
    <template>
<div>
    <select v-model="selected" >
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <span v-for="n in selected" :key="n">{{"hey"}}</span>


</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
      return {
        selected: ''
      }
  },
}
</script>
```

any quick idea? I just returned some string rn, (but it gotta be a component but well i can just replace the string with the component right,) which works if i replace selected with a number like e.g. 5 (then it renders 5 times)

also on a quick note stating the obvious: when i replace "hey" with n , it renders the correct number. (the number, not the number of times, it shows 1 2 3 ... but only once)

Comment: You could us a computed value that is the numerical representation of `selected`. Like `numSelected: () => Number.parseInt(selected)`.

Comment: i know about computed values and i understand what you mean, but can you get a little more into detail?

Comment: See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fc3hmajL/14/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to bind `value` as number like this `:value="1"`

Here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" style="padding:20px">
  <select v-model="selected" >
    <option disabled :value="0">Please select one</option>
    <option :value="1">1</option>
    <option :value="2">2</option>
    <option :value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="i in selected">{{ 'hey' }}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe `selected` should be array?

Comment: oh my because i had no value assigned to the option? thanks ill use this approach :) accepting answer asap

Comment: no `value` in the `<option>` element results in its `innerHTML` as the value. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Comment: @Augusto no in this example it can not be array, it needs another approach

Comment: @Coderz9 You assigned but it considered as string value not number

Comment: ah i figured as much as soon as ferdynator made a statement about using parseint